# Neither ..., nor... and Not ..., nor

Tags: conjunctions, neither-nor

Here two examples of two negative clauses:

> He neither approved my decision, nor did he approve yours.
>
> He didn't approve my decision, nor did he approve yours.

Which variant is right and which is wrong? Or are these variants equivalent?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with these?

Comment: *Neither* is a word that creates a fork - going left and right. You need a parallel construction, missing in #1.

Comment: 1. would work if you changed it a little bit. *He approved neither my decision nor yours.* When *approved* appears after *neither*, we expect to see *disapproved* after *nor*.

Comment: You mean "He neither approved my decision, nor he approved yours."

Comment: The second sounds more idiomatic to me as an American. I'm not sure what Brits would find more natural.

Comment: "nor he approved yours" doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: In casual speech, people go out of their way to avoid both "neither" and "nor".

Comment: Is conjunction "neither / not ..., nor ..." used in oral speech more then in writing?

Comment: Yes, more in speech, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

> He neither **approved my decision**, nor **did *he* approve yours**.

Because the two boldfaced chunks have non-parallel constructions (different grammatical structures), the above sentence is incorrect.

On the other hand, these correct sentences all equivalently convey the quoted sentence's intended meaning:

- He approved neither my decision nor yours.
- He neither approved my decision nor approved yours.

  (There's no good reason to write this sentence unless you are trying to say something like “He neither approved my decision nor *dis*approved yours” instead.)
- He did not approve my decision; neither/nor did he approve yours.
- He did not approve my decision; he did not approve yours either.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think correct answer will be "He neither approved my decision, nor he approved yours.". But I met examples where inversion was used after "nor".

Comment: Here is the link where conjunction "neither ..., nor ..." is used, but after "nor" you can see usage of the inversion.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2

Comment: @АлександрСкворцов *I think correct answer is "He neither approved my decision, nor he approved yours."* No, your new suggestion still does not have the required parallel construction (and is *not* being endorsed by your provided Cambridge Dictionary link). The 2nd and 3rd bullets are the closest alternatives to your suggestions. Why do you not like the 1st bullet, which is as succinct as it gets?